# Core Animation short hand causes odd behaviour

Tags: ios, swift

There's a short form of creating a `CABasicAnimation`, where you can skip setting from and to values. Then the former and current values of the property are used automatically. When the animation is added to the layer, the presentation layer still has the former value of the property, while the layer itself has the new value.

Like this:

```
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true) // disable implicit animation
someLayer.bounds.size.width = 200
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
anim.duration = 2
someLayer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
```

When this short form is used, the animation works fine. But attempts at accessing the presentation layer's `bounds.size.width` during the animation, always return the final value. This isn't the case when from and to are specified; it interpolates. Why is that the case? Shouldn't the presentation layer's properties always reflect how it currently looks?

Comment: As the accepted answer to the linked duplicate says, just don't omit the `fromValue` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Also you can omit the `setDisableActions(true)`.